# ¿Cómo añadir un componente react a una página de mi proyecto que está construido solo en HTML y css?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, reactjs

Tengo un website montado solo con `HTML` y `css`, sin embargo quiero añadir una página adicional con una galería, para lo que quiero utilizar `react-image-gallery`.

Ya cree un proyecto react de prueba y configure la galería, pero no logro renderizar el componente dentro de un `<div>` con el id #**gallery**.

Que método sería el correcto y como debería organizar los directorios de react dentro de mi proyecto?

Comment: he optado por utilizar la libreria swiper y deje de lado React, realmente era demasiado hacer todo esto solo por la libreria react-image-gallery. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para insertar un componente de React en tu HTML necesitas: la librerías React, React-DOM y Babel que permitirá al navegador "entender" JSX, como tu proyecto de HTML y CSS no usa un administrador de paquetes como NPM puedes hacerlo via CDN's. Luego en el HTML creas el elemento donde insertaras el componente, creas
el root en base a ese elemento y le inyectas el componente, aquí un ejemplo sencillo:

[image: files]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- dependencias necesarias -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src=" https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #333">
    <h2>Using react component with plain HTML</h2>
    <div id="react-wrapper"></div> <!-- aqui insertaremos nuestro componente -->
  </div>

  <!-- la propiedad type='text-babel' nos permitira escribir con sintaxis de React -->

  <!-- el script que contiene el componente debe ir antes de la creacion de la raiz -->
  <script type="text/babel" src="Component.js"></script>

  <!-- creamos la raiz y adjuntamos el componente, este se renderizara dentro de 'react-wrapper' -->
  <script type="text/babel" data-presets="env,react" id="react-input">
    ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('react-wrapper')).render(
      <Component></Component>  
    )
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Component.js

```
function Component() {
  const [count, setcount] = React.useState(0)
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setcount(count + 1)}>Click me!</button>
      <br></br>
      <div id="count_elem">Count: {count}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

styles.css:

```
* {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#count_elem {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Esto es sencillo para componentes propios sin ninguna dependencia... pero tu estas usando React-Image-Gallery entonces esto se complica bastante, necesito el código fuente de esa librería entonces como lo hago? via CDN? las librerías de React no están hechas para usarse así y no siempre funcionan (o al menos no pueden usarse de forma intuitiva y no se recomiendan para producción), y que pasa si dicha librería también tiene otras dependencias? Necesitas un gestor de paquetes.

Yo te recomendaría que pruebes a la inversa, intenta pasar tu proyecto de HTML y CSS a React, te va a resultar mucho mas sencillo y vas a obtener los beneficios de la librería y vas a poder agregar mas dependencias fácilmente.

Comment: Hola, me ha quedado claro tu explicación gracias. Este proyecto inicialmente sería muy sencillo y opté por no utilizar algo muy complejo. Ahora, viendo lo que implicaría, realmente no vale la pena que migre todo a React sólo para usar la <code>react-image-gallery</code>. Creo que mejor buscaré una galería que signifique menos problemas, solo quise utilizarla para hacer cambios entre las imágenes con código muy corto a través de useState.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede utilizar `portals`, este método permite insertar un react node dentro de otro elemento HTML externo. Una vez insertado se propagan eventos tal cual están codificados en el arbol React, por lo que no debería haber problemas con la librería que mencionas.

Aquí un demo:

---

```js
function App(){
  
  return (
  <React.Fragment>
     <p>Hola desde DOM</p>
     {ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <p>Hola DOM desde MyGallery!</p>,
        document.getElementById('gallery')
      )}
      
  </React.Fragment>)
  
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
      <App></App>  
    )
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
<div id="gallery"></div>
```

[Portals updated](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal#usage)